# MonoTouch on Device - Vibrates at launch?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, vibration

I just deployed my app to my iPhone for the first time. Every time it launches it vibrates before running, and it runs fine. The build is a Debug | iPhone one of my app.

Any ideas why it vibrates when it launches and how to stop that? It's definitely not something I coded up and I don't have any exceptions or issues when running in the simulator.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The vibration happens when you build the application in debug mode, and run the application without a debugger waiting. The MonoTouch soft debugger vibrates to inform you that it couldn't find the debugger.

Running the app in Release | iPhone mode solves this.

Comment: I think you're right. I can't find any documentation to say that is the case, but it only does it with a debug build. It must be so you know it's debug.

Comment: I just confirmed with the MonoTouch guys, and that is indeed the case. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

The number of vibrations is used to notify the user of a problem setting up debugging at startup.   The full list (that will be maintained as we expand or modify it) is here:

http://monotouch.net/index.php?title=Documentation/Debugging

As of today:

## Device Diagnostics

An application compiled with debug mode that has been deployed on the iPhone will try to contact MonoDevelop on startup on the IP address and port that MonoDevelop had at the time of the build.

If there is an error setting up the debugger, it will vibrate one of more times:

- One vibration: The application was compiled with debugging support, but it is unable to reach MonoDevelop on the specified IP address and port to setup stdout/stderr
- Two vibrations: It is unable to parse the address configured.
- Three vibrations: Could not setup stdout/stderr to the application.

Comment: Love this feature as a concept but it'd be nice if there was some sort of "first time" visual warning. Fortunately there's SO where all things code are documented :)